# Webscraping pages with multiple tabs but one url

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've been trying to scrape the earnings data under the tab "this week" from [trading view earnings](https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/earnings/) using beautiful soup and requests library, but I can't seem to get the data using the basic methods that I know. Unfortunately, the default tab the above link opens to is the "today" tab, and I am not familiar with navigating tabs with the same link.

How can I do this?

Below is something I tried, but it returned an empty list for t:

```
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Chrome/39.0.2171.95'
        }
page = requests.get(
        'https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/earnings/', headers=headers
        )
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='js-screener-container')
t=soup.find_all('tr', {'class':'tv-data-table__row tv-data-table__stroke tv-screener-table__result-row'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see is loaded via JavaScript, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. You can simulate this Ajax request with `requests` module and then feed those data to pandas DataFrame.

Example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

api_url = "https://scanner.tradingview.com/america/scan"

payload = {
    "filter": [
        {"left": "market_cap_basic", "operation": "nempty"},
        {
            "left": "earnings_release_date,earnings_release_next_date",
            "operation": "in_range",
            "right": [1643000400, 1643605200], # <-- probably you need to tweak these values
        },
        {
            "left": "earnings_release_date,earnings_release_next_date",
            "operation": "nequal",
            "right": 1643605200,  # <-- and this value too
        },
    ],
    "options": {"lang": "en"},
    "markets": ["america"],
    "symbols": {"query": {"types": []}, "tickers": []},
    "columns": [
        "logoid",
        "name",
        "market_cap_basic",
        "earnings_per_share_forecast_next_fq",
        "earnings_per_share_fq",
        "eps_surprise_fq",
        "eps_surprise_percent_fq",
        "revenue_forecast_next_fq",
        "revenue_fq",
        "earnings_release_next_date",
        "earnings_release_next_calendar_date",
        "earnings_release_next_time",
        "description",
        "type",
        "subtype",
        "update_mode",
        "earnings_per_share_forecast_fq",
        "revenue_forecast_fq",
        "earnings_release_date",
        "earnings_release_calendar_date",
        "earnings_release_time",
        "currency",
        "fundamental_currency_code",
    ],
    "sort": {"sortBy": "market_cap_basic", "sortOrder": "desc"},
    "range": [0, 150],
}

result = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [r["d"] for r in result["data"]],
    dtype="str",
    columns=[
        "logoid",
        "name",
        "market_cap_basic",
        "earnings_per_share_forecast_next_fq",
        "earnings_per_share_fq",
        "eps_surprise_fq",
        "eps_surprise_percent_fq",
        "revenue_forecast_next_fq",
        "revenue_fq",
        "earnings_release_next_date",
        "earnings_release_next_calendar_date",
        "earnings_release_next_time",
        "description",
        "type",
        "subtype",
        "update_mode",
        "earnings_per_share_forecast_fq",
        "revenue_forecast_fq",
        "earnings_release_date",
        "earnings_release_calendar_date",
        "earnings_release_time",
        "currency",
        "fundamental_currency_code",
    ],
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                         logoid   name    market_cap_basic earnings_per_share_forecast_next_fq earnings_per_share_fq eps_surprise_fq eps_surprise_percent_fq revenue_forecast_next_fq          revenue_fq earnings_release_next_date earnings_release_next_calendar_date earnings_release_next_time                                             description   type subtype            update_mode earnings_per_share_forecast_fq revenue_forecast_fq earnings_release_date earnings_release_calendar_date earnings_release_time currency fundamental_currency_code
0                         apple   AAPL     2779690484608.0                            1.420761                   2.1        0.200885             10.57782177            94209101391.0      123945000000.0                 1651579200                          1648684800                          0                                              Apple Inc.  stock  common  delayed_streaming_900                       1.899115      119002502550.0            1643319000                     1640908800                     1      USD                       USD
1                     microsoft   MSFT     2310984201913.0                            2.192646                  2.48        0.161037              6.94435401            48971705236.0       51728000000.0                 1651147200                          1648684800                          0                                   Microsoft Corporation  stock  common  delayed_streaming_900                       2.318963       50710806541.0            1643144880                     1640908800                     1      USD                       USD
2                         tesla   TSLA   849959567314.9999                            2.238503                  2.54        0.177177              7.49853036            18134248643.0       17719000000.0                 1651665600                          1648684800                          0                                             Tesla, Inc.  stock  common  delayed_streaming_900                       2.362823       17131882446.0            1643231460                     1640908800                     1      USD                       USD
3                          visa      V   479940487395.0001                            1.661801                  1.81        0.107021              6.28434056             6868400149.0        7059000000.0                 1651060800                          1648684800                          0                                               Visa Inc.  stock  common  delayed_streaming_900                       1.702979        6792172282.0            1643320980                     1640908800                     1      USD                       USD
4           johnson-and-johnson    JNJ      452253807870.0                            2.556371                  2.13        0.013477              0.63675188            23810389493.0       24804000000.0                 1650369600                          1648684800                          0                                       Johnson & Johnson  stock  common  delayed_streaming_900                       2.116523       25275614293.0            1643110380                     1640908800                    -1      USD                       USD

...and so on.
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your input! I didn't get to try it yet since I am away from my PC, but I will give you an update and accept your answer once i try it out. On that note, in the example code you say I have to tweak some values. Can you maybe explain what these values represent? Thanks!

Comment: I was busy so answering late, but I figured it out! Thanks